# Eclipse: force project not to show errors for a js directory

Tags: javascript, eclipse

I have a web project that uses a number of 3rd party js libraries. Since they are optimized Eclipse shows that there are errors in these files. I'd like to configure eclipse to ignore certain js directories for error processing and validation.

I think I now have it configured to ignore validation via the validation settings under Project > Properties > Validation > Client Side JavaScript > Settings. I've added an exclude rule for my 3rd party lib directory. My issue is that it still shows errors under Markers > Javascript Problems.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Did you try _Project -> Clean..._?

Comment: I've tried that and it works temporarily. Then when I edit any js files in the project the errors return.

Comment: That means your exclusion rule takes no effect on the builder :(

Comment: Right, I've tried messing with the validation settings under Properties > Validation. I've checked and unchecked the "manual" and "build" checkboxes but it doesn't have any effect.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Client-Side JavaScript validator only validates client-side JavaScript--JavaScript **in web pages**.  You've only instructed it to ignore Javascript in web pages in those folders.  What you want can be done by changing those folders from *Source* folders to  *Library* folders in the JavaScript Include Path.  Project > Properties > JavaScript > Include Path.  Either remove them, or set an exclusion on the Source folder so that it's legal to put a Library folder under it.